# Derivative of NDSolve output

Tags: differential-equations, calculus-and-analysis

I am trying to study the stability of a 2-dimensional discrete system (X, Y) by finding the Jacobian at the systems non-trivial equilibrium (X*, Y*). The functions that map the system from one iterate, n, to the next are given by the solutions to ordinary differential equations solved at time t = T

X(n+1) = f(x(T), y(T))

Y(n+1) = g(x(T), y(T))

where x(T) and y(T) depend on X(n) and Y(n).

Here is a MWE of the problem

```
sol[T_?NumericQ, a_, b_, c_, x0_?NumericQ, y0_?NumericQ] := 
  NDSolve[{
    x'[t] == x0 a - b *x[t]*y[t],
    y'[t] == b*x[t]*y[t] - c y[t],
    x[0] == 0, y[0] == y0}, 
   {x, y}, {t, 0, T]}];

xmap[T_?NumericQ, a_, b_, c_, x0_?NumericQ, y0_?NumericQ] := 
 x[T] /. sol[T, a, b, c, x0, y0]
ymap[T_?NumericQ, a_, b_, c_, h_, j_, x0_?NumericQ, y0_?NumericQ] := 
 h (y[T] /. sol[T, a, b, c, x0, y0])/(1 + 
     j (y[T] /. sol[T, a, b, c, x0, y0]))
```

where x0 and y0 are placeholders for X(n-1) and Y(n-1). Is it possible to take the partial derivatives of xmap and ymap w.r.t. x0 and y0? I tried this

```
D[xmap[5, 0.5, 0.25, 1, x0, 200], x0] /. x0 -> 100
```

But it does not evaluate.

Comment: There are a few typos here - no closing brace in `sol[...{t,0,T]`, `tt` should be `T` in `ymap`. Those aside, I don't think you can apply `NDSolve` to an expression that still has undefined parameters in it (how would you carry out the numerical algorithm?), so you can't take the derivative of it either. Additionally, `xmap` remains unevaluated inside of `D` because you restrict your definition to numerical values of `T`, `x0` and `y0`, so `D` remains unevaluated as well since there is nothing to apply it to.

Comment: Try for instance `f[x_?NumericQ]:=x^2; D[f[x],x]`.

Comment: It looks like you want a numerical answer. Can you use a numerical approximation to the partial at the point of interest? i.e. `(xmap[5,0.5,0.25,1,100+delta,200]-xmap[5,0.5,0.25,1,100-delta,200])/(2*delta)`

Comment: Definition of the derivative will work fine for my purposes. Thanks for the suggestion.